# Adding multiple dialogs to Microsoft botframework dialog stack

Tags: azure, botframework, direct-line-botframework

According to [Microsoft's Botframework Documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-manage-conversation-flow), by using `triggerAction` with `onSelectAction`, you can add dialogs to the top of the stack if a user's utterance includes a matched phrase.

However, if the user's utterance includes TWO matched phrases, how can you add multiple dialogs to the stack?

For example, if a user said...

> I want a burger and fries

I would like to add the `burgers` dialog and the `fries` dialog to the stack, so we can ask questions about both of them.

I've tried something like this:

```
bot.dialog('burgers', require('./burgers'))
    .triggerAction({
        matches: [/burger/i],
            onSelectAction: (session, args, next) => {
                session.beginDialog(args.action, args);
            }
    });

bot.dialog('fries', require('./fries'))
    .triggerAction({
        matches: [/fries/i],
            onSelectAction: (session, args, next) => {
                session.beginDialog(args.action, args);
            }
    });
```

Here's an example of the burgers dialog (the fries dialog is the same):

```
var builder = require('botbuilder');
var Store = require('./store');

module.exports = [
    // Destination
    function (session) {
        session.send('Burger dialog test');
        builder.Prompts.text(session, 'I am just testing the burger dialog');
    },
    function (session, results, next) {
        session.send('Now we should go to the next dialog in the stack', results.response);
        session.endDialog();
    },

];
```

However, only one of the dialogs gets invoked... and then it's game over!

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked my answer? Any update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've found, only one dialog will be triggered at one time, so as a workaround to trigger multiple dialogs, we can trigger one dialog first and analyses the user input to call different child dialog.

For example:

```js
bot.dialog('addOrder', (session, args)=>{
    var text = session.message.text;
    var found = text.match(/burger/i);
    if(found!=null){
        session.beginDialog('burger');
    }
    var found = text.match(/fries/i);
    if(found!=null){
        session.beginDialog('fries');
    }    
}).triggerAction({
    matches: [/burger/i, /fries/i]
});

bot.dialog('burger',(session)=>{
    session.send("burgers");
    //logic of 'burger' dialog
    session.endDialog();
});

bot.dialog('fries', (session)=>{
    session.send("fries!");
    //logic of 'fries' dialog
    session.endDialog();
});
```

As you can see here, we can use a regular expression array to trigger the `addOrder` dialog first and then call other dialogs inside this `addOrder` dialog.

Or you may train a LUIS and use it in your bot like this:

```js
const LuisModelUrl = 'YOUR-BOT-ENDPOINT';
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(LuisModelUrl);
var intents = new builder.IntentDialog({recognizers:[recognizer]})
.matches('MyOrder',(session, args)=>{
   var entities = args.entities;
   //handle entities
});

bot.dialog('/',intents);
```

I create a intent named `MyOrder` and two entities named `MyOrder.Burgers` and `MyOrder.Fries` like this:

[image]